# google mapv2 null pointer exception

Tags: android, google-maps

my code is working fine, when i my trying to display the map,but when i access the googlemap object then it through null pointer exception, so how to overcome it please help

i had followed all the instruction on developer site,
here is my code

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
     GoogleMap googleMap;
     MarkerOptions markerOptions;
     final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
     TextView tvLocInfo;
     boolean markerClicked;
     Button img_cancl,img_done;
     static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
      static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


              if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
            {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(53.558, 9.927)).title("Marker"));
                 Log.i("testing", "success");
            }
            else
            {
             GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
             Log.i("testing", "errorrrrrrrrr");
            }
        }

            }


                @Override
                protected void onResume() {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 super.onResume();

                 int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

                 if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }else{
                  GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
                 }

                }

            }
```

here is my layout

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     tools:context=".MainActivity" >
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tvLocInfo"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="50dp" />
>
>     <fragment
>         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         android:id="@+id/map"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
>         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
> </RelativeLayout>
>
> <include layout="@layout/lay_button" />
> ```

manifest file

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="8"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
>
> <permission
>     android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
>     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
>
> <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
> <uses-feature
>     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
>     android:required="true"/>
>
> <application
>     android:debuggable="true"
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>
>     <meta-data
>         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
>         android:value="AIzaSyBd0XLtX5eHnpHJ7g2XsQ6sntNjDxuS6i4"/>
>
> </application>
> ```

Here is logcat

07-24 10:00:29.051: I/testing(2825): errorrrrrrrrr

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: it shows nullpointer on map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment. A GoogleMap can only be acquired using getMap() when the underlying maps system is loaded and the underlying view in the fragment exists. This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view; however you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. If a GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null.

Comment: is new LatLng(0, 0) is correct or you are missing actual values ?

Comment: googlemap object is not initilizing thats why it throws null pointer, so how to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"my code is working fine" no is not!

You're verifying if GooglePlayServices are installed in onResume(), but you use the GoogleMap object too early in onCreate(). Move the code in onCreate to

```
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ }
```

condition. The GoogleMap object can be null in onCreate and hence the Exception.

You should only use the GoogleMap if you are sure that the GooglePlayServices are passing the mentioned condition.

Comment: what i want to acheive is that,onload i want to display the current location & a marker on it

Comment: And what didn't you understand from my response? What I am telling you will make what you want. Maybe you do not have GooglePlayServices installed and the popup from onResume() is not showing because your app crashes in onCreate().

Comment: i tried that as well but googlemap object is not initializd onload, so how to access map object

Comment: i got what i want to acheive, i am accessing map object on resume & not oncreate,it works thnx @emil